# Is there a way to concisely write anonymous subtrait with only one abstract method?

Tags: scala, function, traits

When writing tests in `Scalatest` I used the so called `Equality[A]` trait which looks as (documentation omitted):

```
trait Equality[A] extends Equivalence[A] {
  def areEqual(a: A, b: Any): Boolean 
  final def areEquivalent(a: A, b: A): Boolean = areEqual(a, b)
}
```

I currently implement it as following

```
implicit def positionEquality: Equality[SomeType] = new Equality[SomeType] {
    override def areEqual(a: SomeType, b: Any): Boolean = b match {
        //actual code
    }
}
```

But I'd like to write it more concisely... like function literal or some. Is there something like that?

UPD: I could only imagine some implicit conversion, but it looks quite weird as that I will have to bring it into scope explicitly every time I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala 2.12

```
implicit def positionEquality: Equality[SomeType] = (a, b) => b match ...
```

[should work](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types). In Scala 2.11 it requires `-Xexperimental` compiler options (IIRC, there are cases it doesn't work correctly; unfortunately I don't know exactly what they are and if this is one of them, but I wouldn't expect so).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
object Equality {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](fun: (a: T, b: T) => Boolean) = new Equality[T] {
    override def areEqual(a: T, b: Any): Boolean = b match {
      case t: T => fun(a, t)
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}

implicit def positionEquality: Equality[SomeType] = Equality({case (a, b) => ???})
```

Or go the [Eq](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/kernel/Eq.html) route and let the compiler help you with `Any`.

Comment: Matching against `T` in this case doesn't actually work. You need `def apply[T: ClassTag]` for this.

Comment: Right, reflection.